# Передача в модальное окно кнопки, которая его открыла

Tags: javafx

У меня есть окно, на нём три кнопки. Каждая открывает одно и то же модальное окно. На модальном окне есть компонент ListView и я хочу что бы при открытии окна в ListView загружался один из трёх ObservableList, в зависимости от нажатой кнопки.

Знаю, что можно сделать так: в главном окне создать переменную и по нажатии какой-либо кнопки присвоить этой переменной значение, идентифицирующее нажатую кнопку и создать метод который будет эту переменную возвращать. Далее в модальном окне вызывать метод который вернет переменную и в зависимости от неё загружать нужный ObservableList в ListView. Но грамотно ли это?

Можно ли сделать так: из модального окна обратиться к родительскому окну, получить объект события и с помощью этого объекта события определить какая из трёх кнопок была нажата?[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

Я думаю вариантов реализации может быть множество (зависит от выбранного архитектурного подхода, например иным вариантом может быть использование системы событий).

Суть этого подхода: все три кнопки вызывают один и тоже метод, но с разными параметрами. В роли параметра может выступать как сам список (как в примере), так и некоторое значение, которое передается второму окну (на основании этого значения окно самостоятельно сформирует и отобразит список).

Т.к. все три кнопки работают с одним окном (которое может быть закрыто и не использоваться), то желательно использование WeakReference (для своевременной очистки памяти)

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

import java.lang.ref.WeakReference;

public class Main extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        Button button = new Button();
        button.setOnAction(event -> showMyStage(FXCollections.observableArrayList("1", "2", "3")));

        Button button1 = new Button();
        button1.setOnAction(event -> showMyStage(FXCollections.observableArrayList("4", "5", "6")));;

        Button button2 = new Button();
        button2.setOnAction(event -> showMyStage(FXCollections.observableArrayList("7", "8", "9")));

        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(new VBox(button, button1, button2)));
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    private WeakReference<MyStage> myStageRef;

    private void showMyStage(ObservableList<String> items) {
        MyStage myStage = myStageRef == null ? null : myStageRef.get();
        if ( myStage == null ) {
            myStage = new MyStage();
            myStageRef = new WeakReference<>(myStage);
        }
        myStage.getListView().setItems(items);
        if ( !myStage.isShowing() ) {
            myStage.show();
        }
    }

}
```

MyStage

```
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.ListView;
import javafx.stage.Modality;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class MyStage extends Stage {

    public ListView<String> getListView() { return listView; }
    private ListView<String> listView;

    public MyStage() {
        initModality(Modality.NONE);
        listView = new ListView<>();
        setScene(new Scene(listView, 300, 300));
    }

}
```